# Can someone tell me why it is failing?

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(['a'], function(){$('<a/>').text(this).appendTo('body');});
```

=> firefox and chrome told me that 'appendTo' is not a function...

Comment: Could you tell someone what you are trying to do?

Comment: Expected result: append '<a>a</a>' to body

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking this was your first q. Is evert answer you asked before note answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.each(['a'], function(idx, elem){$('<a/>').text(elem).appendTo('body');});
```

Or even better, just use a `for` loop:

```
var elements = ['a'];
for (var i in elements) {
    $('<a/>').text(elements[i]).appendTo('body');
}
```

It's both easier to read and faster to execute.

Comment: Yes, indeed but 'this' should be the current string, right ? Or maybe it was true only for older versions of jQuery...

Comment: To see what happens, try running: `$.each(['a'], function(){console.log(this);});`

Comment: I already did exactly this. And firefox log a string. That's why I can't understand...

Comment: @Tom Esterez, you'll see `[object Object]` in Chrome. If you use `this.toString()` instead, you'll get a string. So, with your code, `$.each(['a'], function(){$('<a/>').text(this.toString()).appendTo('body');});`

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what is this object ? And why Firefox console says that it is a string ??

Answer (score 0):

`$('<a/>')` should this be `$('a')`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the `text` function return a string object, not a jQuery object?

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` is a function which sets the text, but I don't think you can chain it together. Try opening up that line:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var a = $('<a/>');
  a.text($(this));
  $('body').append(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

Perhaps something more like?
    $('a').each(function(){$('body').append('')});